# Good learning resources for Maven 3/Mercury

Tags: maven-3

I've been trying to find out more about Maven 3 and Mercury (Maven Mercury is a replacement for the Maven Artifact subsystem, and a complete replacement for the HTTP/HTTPS/DAV/DAVS portions of the existing transport).

There seems to be very little of substance available at the moment, particularly for Maven 3.

Does anyone know of any guides/tutorials/plans/roadmaps?

I've found these resources so far:

- [Presentation by Jason van Zyl on Maven 3](http://www.scribd.com/doc/14458957/Jasons-Maven-3-Presentation)
- [Mercury architecture](http://maven.apache.org/mercury/index.html)
- [Codehaus Mercury site](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Mercury)
- [Sonatype blog on Mercury ant tasks](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/12/mercury-ant-tasks-howto/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you saw it but there is a video of Jason's Maven 3 presentation on Sonatype's website: [Maven Meetup: Jason van Zyl on Maven 3](http://www.sonatype.com/events/meetup0309/jason-on-maven3).

But, in my opinion, the best resource to learn about Maven 3 is the [Maven Developers](http://maven.markmail.org/search/?q=#query:list%3Aorg.apache.maven.dev+page:1+state:facets) list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the same video as the first item in my list (can't be sure as I can't access the site at work though)

Comment: The first item in your list points on presentation material, there is no video of Jason's talk. But I confirm that the slides are the same in both cases.

Comment: +1 for the mailing list anyway. Should have included that in my list

Answer (score 2):

Sonatype have posted an [interview with Benjamin Bentman](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/09/maven-30-technology-preview-interview-with-benjamin-bentman/) discussing API changes and main features of Maven 3.

They also mention that the  developer builds of [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) are now using Maven 3, and provide a link to the [Maven 3.x Compatibility Wiki](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes)

Update: Another [Sonatype blog on Maven 3](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/11/maven-3x-paving-the-desire-lines-part-one-2/). Outlines a number of the issues with Maven2 and what is being done in Maven 3 to address them.

Answer (score 2):

The [Sonatype tag "maven"](http://www.sonatype.com/people/tag/maven/) remains a good official source of information on Maven in general, and Maven3 in particular.

Note: I was the [ParisJUG (Java User Group)](http://translate.google.fr/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.parisjug.org%2Fxwiki%2Fbin%2Fview%2FMeeting%2F20100511&sl=fr&tl=en) yesterday, which included a Maven 3 presentation.
Mercury was said to be **[retired from Maven3](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/retired/)** itself...

Comment: See also http://twitter.com/aheritier/status/13357341875 ("No, Maven 3 does *not* use Mercury. I'm tired of reading that everywhere!")

Comment: Is there any official announcement of why Mercury was retired?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Defintively [removed in may 2010](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-commits/201005.mbox/%3C20100505163329.61A0223888CC@eris.apache.org%3E), Mercury was too big, and replaced by a [leaner "Aether"](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2010/08/introducing-aether/1347829233000/#.Ukx0Gz_9W-M) (standard library for interacting with Maven repositories).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen From the last "Aether" link: "Mercury was our first attempt at extracting a Repository API from Maven and that didn’t work. We bit off more then we could chew, and so our first attempt was a learning experience. We attempted to integrate the excellent [SAT4J library](http://www.sat4j.org/) but didn’t have enough experience to pull that off."

Answer (score 0):

There is also a video presentation about Maven 3 and other new projects at [JavaZone 2010](http://streaming.java.no/tcs/#page%3arecordingList&pageNumber:1&id:0FF55F2E-CC69-4FF8-B28F-6BC3A08B9665)